# Convert type of dictionary value in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In the dictionary below some of the `record_id` are in list and some are in string. I'm trying to convert all the values of `record_id` to list.

```
list_of_dict =      
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': [4679], 'flag': 'N'}, 
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': 4678, 'flag': 'N'}]
```

I've tried below code:

```
for each in result:
    record_value = each['record_id']
    record_value = str(record_value)
    print(type(record_value))
    if type(record_value)1= list:
        record_value = record_value.split()
        each['record_id'] = record_value
```

expected output:

```
list_of_dict =      
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4680', '4679'], 'flag': 'N'},
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': ['4678'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

please guide me with the solution

Comment: are single values strings or integers. It seems to be integers

Comment: @CodeBuster17 record_id values are either integer "record_id':4679 or 'record_id':[4678] or list of integer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert split values. Simply check if type is `int` and then wrap with a list:

```
for item in list_of_dict:
    if type(item["record_id"]) == int:
        item["record_id"] = [str(item["record_id"])]
    else:
        item["record_id"] = [str(i) for i in item["record_id"]]
```

*Of note, if the `record_id`s are always numeric consider storing them as so instead of as strings.*

Comment: i've edited my input...my record_id values are either integer "record_id':4679 or 'record_id':[4678] or list of integer.

Comment: @sruthi - see update. Simply convert the nested items to string